# Am trying to regenerate a scatterplot after removing the points that I have clicked

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, interaction

I am trying to do the following
a. Generate a scatter plot

b. when user clicks on a point, the details related to that point is shown using the nearpoints feature

c. When user chooses to delete that clicked data point from the chart, I go back to remove the datapoint from the original dataset, using a flag. Somehow this step doesnt seem to work.

here is the code.Any pointers would be much appreciated

```
ui<- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("Scatterplot", click = "plot_click"),

  actionButton("updateData", "Update data by removing the clicked datapoint"),
  #actionButton("refreshline", "Rline"),
  dataTableOutput("info"),

  verbatimTextOutput("data")

)

server<- function(input, output)
{
 # data for plot
  x1 <- c(3, 10, 15, 3, 4, 7, 1, 12, 8, 18, 20, 4, 4, 5, 10)   #x
  x2 <- c(4, 10, 12, 17, 15, 20, 14, 3, 4, 15, 12, 5, 5, 6, 2)
  scatter_plot_show<- rep(1, 15)
  df<- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,scatter_plot_show))

  plot_data <- reactive({
    plot_data <- df %>% 
      dplyr:: filter (scatter_plot_show == 1  )
  })

  output$Scatterplot <- renderPlot({
     ggplot(plot_data(),aes(x= x1, y=x2)) +
      geom_point()         
  })

# use near points to get x1 clicked by user
  nearpoints_data <- reactive({
    nearpoints_df<- as.data.frame(nearPoints(plot_data(), input$plot_click, xvar= "x1", yvar= "x2"))

    nearpoints_df1 <- plot_data() %>% 
      dplyr::filter(x1 %in% nearpoints_df$x1)
  })

#show X1,X2 of data point that was clicked by the user
  output$info <- renderDataTable({
    #input$plot_click
    DT::datatable(nearpoints_data())
  })
  # when user clicks, update data, remove the datapoint and render the scatter plot
  observeEvent(
    input$updateData,
    { plot_data<- plot_data() %>% mutate( scatter_plot_show=replace(scatter_plot_show,  x1 %in% nearpoints_data()$x1,0))

    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer using some examples given in the Shiny Gallery. I am listing down the solution for others benefit

```
options(shiny.reactlog= TRUE)

ui<- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("Scatterplot", click = "plot_click"),
    actionButton("Exclude_points", "Exclude points"),
  actionButton("Reset", "Reset"),
  #actionButton("refreshline", "Rline"),
  tableOutput("info"),
  tableOutput("df"),
  verbatimTextOutput("data")

)

server<- function(session,input, output)
{

  x1 <- c(3, 10, 15, 3, 4, 7, 1, 12, 8, 18, 20, 4, 4, 5, 10)   #x
  x2 <- c(4, 10, 12, 17, 15, 20, 14, 3, 4, 15, 12, 5, 5, 6, 2)
  df<- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2)) # df defined within the app

   rv<- reactiveValues(keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(df))) # initial keeprows to select all rows

  output$Scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    keep<-  df [rv$keeprows,, drop=FALSE]
      ggplot(keep,aes(x= x1, y=x2)) +
      geom_point() 
  })


  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    res <- nearPoints(df, input$plot_click, allRows = TRUE)
    rv$keeprows <- xor(rv$keeprows, res$selected_) # keeprows are removed from df upon plot_clicks
  })

  output$info <- renderTable({
    rv$keeprows
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I do have a follow on question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577309/unable-to-exclude-points-from-a-plot-if-the-dataset-is-reactive